# Working with WHERE IN on Stored Procedure (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

### The goal

Passing multiple values through a single `VARCHAR()` parameter.

### The scenario

On my application there is a procedure that get products from some table. What I need is simple: take three (or whatever) results by `id` if I pass it. For example:
`CALL getProducts('1, 2, 3');`.

To do this, I'm working with `IN` clause. Take a look at my query:

```
BEGIN
    Select product.Name
    From app_products As product
    Where product.Id In (1, 2, 3)
END
```

How can I pass those `1, 2, 3` by parameter?

### What I've already tried

Take a look in my query with its parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getProductsPrices`(IN `ids` VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    Select product.Name
    From app_products As product
    Where product.Id In (ids)
END
```

Now, when I call it:

```
CALL `getProductsPrices`('1, 2, 3')
```

The return is:

> Warning: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE '1, 2, 3'

Someone has any suggestion for me?

### Duplicated?

I think that this topic isn't duplicated because I already searched by the same subject but with no success.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149545/pass-array-to-mysql-stored-routine

Comment: @Declan_K The question appears to be the same, but I don't think it is because the solution passed doesn't solved my problem.

Comment: Then you should try again, because these solutions definitely answer your question. You might want to check that your query (build manually) actually returns what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up dynamic SQL

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE `getProductsPrices` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `getProductsPrices`(IN `ids` VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'Select product.Name From app_products';
    SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql,' As product Where product.Id In (',`ids`,')');
    PREPARE s FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE s;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: There is a syntax error on `CONCAT()`, @RolandoMySQLDBA? I ask this because when I execute the query, a `syntax error at line 4 near ''` is displayed for me.

Comment: I think mysql did not like the line break. Please Try Again.

Comment: I was unaware of this problem of "one line" from MySQL. You resolved my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Probably not really index friendly, but you may be able to use the [find_in_set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) function...

```
where find_in_set(product.id, ids)
```

Otherwise you need to parse the delimitted string into a temp table and join with the table.

Comment: Didn't worked for me. I tried `CALL `getProductsPrices`('1, 2, 3')` but the return is just the first piece of the parameter (in our case, 1).

Comment: Might need to typecast product.id to a string.  Rolando's answer will probably work better though, and should deal with indexes properly.