# Stored Procedure with a IN statement (mysql)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a query like

```
Select id,name,... FROM table WHERE id IN (?)
```

The query is actually more complicated with joins and another (?) with the same ids. I've been told to put it on a stored procedure to make it easier to manage and safer, but mysql doesn't support arrays, so I'm not sure what is the best way to do it, considering that I don't know how many id I will have to pass. I have seen people passing a string. Is it the only way?

Comment: You can use temporary tables. Similar question is [Pass array to MySQL stored routine][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149545/pass-array-to-mysql-stored-routine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use temporary tables. Though this answer is not highly voted so I suppose that using a string parameter is the prefered way (17 votes vs 2 votes) (see the link). The answer with temporary table is taken from another question: [Pass array to MySQL stored routine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149545/pass-array-to-mysql-stored-routine)

> Use a join with a temporary table. You don't need to pass temporary
>   tables to functions, they are global.

```
create temporary table ids( id int ) ;
insert into ids values (1),(2),(3) ;

delimiter //
drop procedure if exists tsel //
create procedure tsel() -- uses temporary table named ids. no params
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
  -- use the temporary table `ids` in the SELECT statement or
  -- whatever query you have
  select * from Users INNER JOIN ids on userId=ids.id ;
END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL tsel() ; -- call the procedure
```